# Почему форма отправляется в 2 разные таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, post, form

Всем привет, не могу решить такую проблему. Есть два Class'a support.php и subscribe.php. Цель у них проста, Class subscribe.php выполняется в sidebar.php, и там находится только одно поля видите email и кнопка  submit, и меэл добавляется в таблицу. Вторая форма находится в footer.php которая связана support.php и там 3 поля форма и одна из них email. Вопрос в том почему когда что-то отправляется через index.php куда подключены и sidebar и footer, они цепляют другу и заполняются обе в таблицы в базе данных?

Коды классов:
subscribe.php

```
<?php
class subscribe
{
// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "Subscribe";

// object properties
public $id;
public $email;

public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn = $db;
}

function create(){
    //write query
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " (email)" .
        "VALUES ('{$this->email}');";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // posted values
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $this->email);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

support.php

```
<?php
class support {
// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "ContactUs";

// object properties
public $id;
public $name;
public $theme;
public $email;

public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn = $db;
}

function support(){
    //write query
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "(name, theme, email)" .
        "VALUES ('{$this->name}','{$this->theme}','{$this->email}');";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // posted values
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->theme=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->theme));
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":theme", $this->theme);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $this->email);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

sidebar.php

```
$subscribe = new subscribe($db);
if($_POST){
$subscribe->email = $_POST['email'];
if($subscribe->create()){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>You have successfully subscribed 
to the newsletter. <br>
    The newsletter about new out products will be sent to your e-mail 
address.</div>";
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to create product.</div>";
}
```

}

footer.php

```
$support = new support($db);
if($_POST){
$support->name = $_POST['name'];
$support->theme = $_POST['theme'];
$support->email = $_POST['email'];
if($support->support()){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you, for question. <br> We 
will be in touch soon..</div>";
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to create product.</div>";
}
}
```

Форма отправляется через:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Почему вы добавили картинку, а не код как текст?

Comment: Исправил, добавил код

Comment: Ну судя по названиям таблиц в одной хранятся контакты, во второй подписки. для подписок нужен только email, к контактам он отношения не имеет. Одно может существовать без другого. Наличие контакта не означает, что он должен быть на что то подписан. Так что наверное логично, что это две разные сущности. А в приведенном вами коде в sidebar.php нет упоминаний класса subscribe, так что совершенно не ясно из чего вы заключили, что он тут используется. На лицо только, скорее всего не нужное, дублирование одинакового кода обращения к support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`** и **`if($_POST)`** отрабатывают одинаково. При отправке одной из форм, а они у вас обрабатываются в тех же файлах что и находятся, парсер проходит по этим двум проверкам **`$_POST`**  и выполняет код внутри. А так как у вас ещё и имена полей одинаковые в разных формах, используются одни и те же данные **`$_POST`**.

**Рецепт:**

Если не можете использовать обработчики форм в отдельных файлах, делайте при отправке формы её идентификацию:

```
<input type="hidden" value="form1" /> // отправлена форма с таким полем
...
if($_POST && $_POST['form1']) { // отработает

if($_POST && $_POST['form2']) { // не отработает
```